# LIke functoin view keep throwing DoesNotExist at /group/3/ after a second user in the group post when liked by another user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am currently challenge with a like functionality on a group page for that I'm creating, the problem is that when a first user of the group post on the group page other users can comment and like at his post, but as soon as a second user of the same group post, then when the post get liked or commented on, it throws thess error DoesNotExist at /group/3/. i wonder why am getting this error, because when the first user posted it didn't throw that error, when his post got liked or commented on, but the error only shows up when a another user on the same group post and it got like or commented on. I would appreciate some help. Here is my like function view.

```
def like(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    group = GroupEx.objects.get(group=pk)
    liked= False
    like = Like.objects.filter(username=user, post=post,group=group)
    if like:
        like.delete()
    else:
        liked = True
        Like.objects.create(username=user, post=post, group=group)
    resp = {
        'liked':liked
    }
    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return redirect('group:main', pk=pk)
    return HttpResponse(response,content_type = "application/json")
```

Here is my comment view.

```
def comment(request, pk):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    group = get_object_or_404(GroupEx,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.post = post
            data.group = group
            data.username = user
            data.save()
            return redirect('group:main', pk=pk)
    else:
        form = NewCommentForm()
        
    context['form'] = form  
    return render(request,'group/grouptimeline.html',context)
```

Here this model for the group post .

```
class Post(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupEx, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="group_post")
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,related_name="group_user")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/post/img' ,blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupEx, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="group_comment")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='g_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='g_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=5000)


class Like(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(GroupEx, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="group_liker")
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='g_likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='g_likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like_date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: What is the `GroupEx` doing in the view?

Comment: To relate the comment  and like to that particular group name  in the database.!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I figured out that when i add an ID parameter to the like function view and  redirect to another Url without the pk or id it works perfectly , but as soon as i redirect to the same URL where the post was created i get the error again, and i also tried adding id to where the post was created but i still get the error, with the Id  where  post was created, please do you have any suggestions. on how  to redirect to  where the post was actually created. when i redirect to this("group:groups") which is the listview.it works .I want the redirect to where the post was created.